# Как расширить объект родительского класса в дочерний?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, наследование, lxml

У меня есть класс `Operator`, который будет добавлять ряд полезных методов и, быть может, атрибутов к *xml*-элементу, характеризующему оператор алгоритма Метрополиса-Гастингса:

```py
class Operator(lxml.etree._Element):
    tune_attributes = {
        "scaleOperator": "scaleFactor",
        "deltaExchange": "delta",
        "upDownOperator": "scaleFactor",
    }
    loggable = True

    def tune(self, n: str | float) -> NoReturn:
        if loggable:
            print(
                f"Tuning {self.tag} (idrefs: {', '.join(ref for ref in self.xpath('descendant::*/@idref'))}) from {self.attrib[tune_attributes[self.tag]]} to {n}"
            )
        self.attrib[tune_attributes[self.tag]] = n
```

Операторы получаются через метод `xpath` из `lxml`.  Результат – это список объектов типа `lxml.etree._Element`.

Хотелось бы, что бы сохраняя все свои свойства они превратились в соответсвующие объекты класса `Operator`, просто неся теперь набор дополнительных методов.

И здесь я в затруднении, как это красиво, практично и по-питонячьи провернуть.

`_Element` не имеет своего собственного метода `__init__`, поэтому я не знаю, возможно ли это как-то через `super().__init__`.

Добавлять новые методы сразу к классу `_Element` через `lxml.etree._Element.tune = tune` выглядит нехорошей практикой, так как они нужны только операторам, а не всем возможным элементам *xml*-дерева.

Добавление всего набора методов к каждому полученному оператору по отдельности через `types.MethodType(tune, some_operator)` всё равно похоже на костыль. Да и класс в последних двух случаях не меняется.

Когда-то для подобных случаев использовал следующий обходной путь, но тоже сомневаюсь, что это выглядит как **хороший** код:

```py
class Operator(lxml.etree._Element):
    def __new__(cls, element):
        element.__class__ = cls
        return element
```

Можете, пожалуйста, подсказать хороший с точки зрения практичности, явности и хорошего стиля разработки способ превратить объект одного класса в дочернего с сохранением всех свойств?

Comment: Т.к. `__init__` у класса отсутствует, то это значит что все значения устанавливаются вручную. Вам придётся сделать тоже самое. Что то вроде такого `self.text = obj.text;self.tag = obj.tag;...`

Comment: @Danis Вот этого я и пытаюсь избежать.

Answer (score 0):

После долгого прошаривания темы не нашёл у других людей ничего лучше моего варианта с `__new__`. Например, вот ответ с [заморского](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49795902/17309108). В отличие от его автора, считаю, что если не предполагается или отсутствует возможность создать и проинициализировать объект независимо, то лучше использовать `__new__` как встроенный конструктор, а не `@classmethod`.

Таким образом:

```py
Element = lxml.etree._Element

class Operator(Element):
    def __new__(cls, element: Element):
        assert isinstance(element, Element)
        element.__class__ = cls
        assert isinstance(element, Operator)
        return element
```